# Ruby - Problems with Expect and Pty

Tags: ruby, expect, pty

I'm trying to write a Ruby script that will ssh over to a server, run a given command, and fetch the output from it. Here's what I've got so far, mostly adapted from the [Programming Ruby](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby) book:

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

$expect_verbose = true
PTY.spawn("ssh root@x.y") do |reader, writer, pid|
  reader.expect(/root@x.y's password:.*/)
  writer.puts("password")
  reader.expect(/.*/)
  writer.puts("ls -l")
  reader.expect(/.*/)
  answer = reader.gets
  puts "Answer = #{answer}"
end
```

Unfortunately all I'm getting back is this:

```
Answer = .y's password:
```

Any idea what I've done wrong and how to alleviate this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this I recommend using the net-ssh gem: `sudo gem install net-ssh`: http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v2/api/index.html

The code goes a little like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('your-server', 'username', :password => "password") do |ssh|
  puts ssh.exec!("ls -la")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.42klines.com/2010/08/14/what-to-expect-from-the-ruby-expect-library.html - it has some nice examples of using PTY with and without Ruby's expect.

I often find it easier to only use PTY, as I can look at my "buffer" and work out what's happening.